# Is there a way to make python repeatedly print the input function multiple times while still getting an answer in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
grades = int (input('Enter grade:'))

if grades >= 90 <= 100:
    print ('A+')
elif grades >= 80 < 90:
    print ('A')
elif grades >= 70 < 80:
    print ('B')
elif grades >= 60 < 70:
    print ('C')
elif grades >= 50 < 60:
    print ('D')
elif grades >= 40 < 50:
    print ('E')
elif grades >= 30 < 40:
    print ('F')
elif grades >= 30 <= 0:
    print ('U')
else:
    print ('Invalid Number')
```

So far, the only thing I can do is copy and paste the whole thing multiple times

Comment: Your conditions are written wrong. `grades >= 90 <= 100` means `grades >= 90 and 90 <= 100`.

Comment: Write your conditions as `90<= grades <= 100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the entire code and you've got your answer:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    grades = int (input('Enter grade:'))

    if grades >=90 and grades <= 100:
        print ('A+')
    elif grades >= 80 and grades < 90:
        print ('A')
    elif grades >= 70  and grades < 80:
        print ('B')
    elif grades >= 60  and grades < 70:
        print ('C')
    elif grades >= 50  and grades < 60:
        print ('D')
    elif grades >= 40  and grades < 50:
        print ('E')
    elif grades >= 30  and grades < 40:
        print ('F')
    elif grades >= 30  and grades <= 0:
        print ('U')
    else:
        print ('Invalid Number')
```

Change '10' in the for statement to whatever value you need. Or, if you want it to go on forever, just use `while(1)`.

That should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it a function. But without more context, I can't help.

```
def get_grades:
    grades = int (input('Enter grade:'))

    if grades >= 90  and grades <= 100:
        print ('A+')
    elif grades >= 80 and grades < 90:
        print ('A')
    elif grades >= 70 and grades < 80:
        print ('B')
    elif grades >= 60 and grades < 70:
        print ('C')
    elif grades >= 50 and grades < 60:
        print ('D')
    elif grades >= 40 and grades < 50:
        print ('E')
    elif grades >= 30 and grades < 40:
        print ('F')
    elif grades >= 0 and grades <= 30:
        print ('U')
    else:
        print ('Invalid Number')
    return grades
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check every value separatelly

```
grades >= 90 and grades <= 100
```

---

```
if grades >= 90 and grades <= 100:
    print ('A+')
elif grades >= 80 and grades < 90:
    print ('A')
elif grades >= 70 and grades < 80:
    print ('B')
elif grades >= 60 and grades < 70:
    print ('C')
elif grades >= 50 and grades < 60:
    print ('D')
elif grades >= 40 and grades < 50:
    print ('E')
elif grades >= 30 and grades < 40:
    print ('F')
elif grades >= 0 and grades < 30:
    print ('U')
else:
    print ('Invalid Number')
```

---

Or shorter

```
90 <= grades <= 100
```

---

```
if 90 <= grades <= 100:
    print ('A+')
elif 80 <= grades < 90:
    print ('A')
elif 70 <= grades < 80:
    print ('B')
elif 60 <= grades < 70:
    print ('C')
elif 50 <= grades < 60:
    print ('D')
elif 40 <= grades < 50:
    print ('E')
elif 30 <= grades < 40:
    print ('F')
elif 0 <= grades < 30:
    print ('U')
else:
    print ('Invalid Number')
```

---

But you can also reduce it (because previous `if/elif` checks second value for next `if/elif`)

```
if grades > 100:
    print('Invalid Number')
elif grades >= 90:
    print ('A+')
elif grades >= 80:
    print ('A')
elif grades >= 70:
    print ('B')
elif grades >= 60:
    print ('C')
elif grades >= 50:
    print ('D')
elif grades >= 40:
    print ('E')
elif grades >= 30:
    print ('F')
elif grades >= 0:
    print ('U')
else:
    print('Invalid Number')
```

or (the same with `<=` instead of `>=`)

```
if 100 < grades
    print('Invalid Number')
elif 90 <= grades:
    print ('A+')
elif 80 <= grades:
    print ('A')
elif 70 <= grades:
    print ('B')
elif 60 <= grades:
    print ('C')
elif 50 <= grades:
    print ('D')
elif 40 <= grades:
    print ('E')
elif 30 <= grades:
    print ('F')
elif 0 <= grades:
    print ('U')
else:
    print('Invalid Number')
```